# How to check if object id in array is the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to compare an object id with all id's of the objects in the array.

So I have a button where I can add a dish to the orders array. When it does not exists in the array than push it to the array. But when it does exist replace the current one with the new dish object.

it looks something like this:

```
const dish = {id:1, quantity: 4};

// This will be filled by an array push
const orders = [
  {id: 1, dish: {id:1, quantity: 1}},
  {id: 2, dish: {id:3, quantity: 5}},
  {id: 3, dish: {id:5, quantity: 1}},
  {id: 4, dish: {id:2, quantity: 3}},
  {id: 5, dish: {id:8, quantity: 1}}
]
```

So basically I have an `orderID` and a `dishID`

What I have tried:

```
addToCart(dish){

  const index = this.orders.findIndex((e) => e.id === dish.id);

   if(index >= 0){
      console.log('INDEX1', this.orders, index);
      this.orders[index] = {id: this.orders[index].id, dish: this.orders[index].dish};
   } else {
      this.orderCounter = this.orderCounter + 1;
      this.orders.push({id: this.orderCounter, dish: dish});
   }
}
```

The `index` returns -1 when I add the third dish item two times which looks like this:

```
dish = {id: 3, quantity: 2}
```

Than the orders array looks like this:

```
const orders = [
  {id: 0, dish: {id:1, quantity: 1}},
  {id: 1, dish: {id:3, quantity: 2}},
  {id: 2, dish: {id:3, quantity: 2}},
]
```

Could somebody help me out I appreciate it :)

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Why not a `Set()` and not worry about this ordering layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.id` is the order id, you probably want `e.dish.id`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to search for an object whose `dish.id` property already exists, with your actual code you are comparing to the `order id`. Also, I have made some other minor changes to fix your code, check below:

```js
const orders = [
    {id: 0, dish: {id:1, quantity: 1}},
    {id: 1, dish: {id:3, quantity: 2}}
];

let orderCounter = 1;

function addToCart(dish)
{
   const index = orders.findIndex(({dish:{id}}) => id === dish.id);

   if (index >= 0)
   {
      orders[index].dish = dish;
   }
   else
   {
      orders.push({id: ++orderCounter, dish: dish});
   }
}

addToCart({id: 3, quantity: 5});
addToCart({id: 7, quantity: 3});
console.log(orders);
```

Comment: Please, let me know what is wrong with my answer so I can improve it or delete it corresponds, thanks!